# optimize JavaScript setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

What would be a better way of writing this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#clock').animate({
        'marginTop': '-20px'
    }, 'slow', $.bez(bezierEasing));
}, 100);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#submit').animate({
        'top': '-5px'
    }, 500, $.bez(bezierEasing));
}, 200);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#details').animate({
        'top': '-200px'
    }, 500, $.bez(bezierEasing));
}, 300);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#details').animate({
        'top': '19px'
    }, 100, $.bez(bezierEasing));
}, 600);
```

Comment: Not sure why I was down voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "help me make this better" questions without some helpful descriptions of the problems you have with it, or the parts you think are awkward, or anything like that, well that does not provide much direction to people trying to help. What are the things about your code that make you want it to be "better"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function:

```
// adjust your function accordingly...
function animateIt(selector, speed, top) {
   setTimeout(function() {
    $(selector).animate({
     'top': top
    },   speed, $.bez(bezierEasing));
   }, 600);    
}
```

Comment: @hkutluay: Yes that's why I have written `adjust your function accordingly...`. That should be easy :)

Comment: If I wanted to sometimes use Margin. Would that be possible to add that into the same function?

Comment: @user1381806: Yes pass margin parameter to function and use that like in my example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using some weird timeOut chain why you don't use [TimelineMax](http://www.greensock.com/v12/) from greensock.com.

It's far more advanced and way easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing out my version...

```
function animateEl(selector, css, speed, timer) {
   var tmp = parseInt(speed, 10);
   if (!isNaN(tmp)) {
      speed = tmp;
   }
   return setTimeout(function () {
      $(selector).animate(css, speed, $.bez(bezierEasing) 
   }, timer);
}

animateEl('#clock', {'marginTop': '-20px' }, 'slow',  100);
animateEl('#submit', { 'top': '-5px' }, 500, , 200);
animateEl('#details', { 'top': '-200px' }, 500, 300);
animateEl('#details', { 'top': '19px' }, 100,  600);
```